# Not showing variable stored in session in afterDisconnect(), sails.js

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, sails.js

I'm saving `req.session.user = user; // where user contains single user object`

and then `console.log(req.session.user.user_id); // this works here`

 but in the socket.js file, in the afterDisconnect function the `session.user` is not available.

Following is the code for afterDisconnect function

```
    afterDisconnect: function(session, socket, cb) {
        console.log(session); // this is not the one that we used above, it's new. Why?
        User.findOne({user_id: session.user.user_id})
            .exec(function(err, user){
            if(err) res.serverError();

            user.online = false;
            user.save();
            });

        return cb();
    }
```

It shows following error when the user / socket disconnects.

```
warn: Socket disconnected, but session could not be loaded to pass to configured disconnect handler: `sails.config.sockets.onDisconnect()`.  Will pass a fake, empty session as argument to lifecycle callback.  Details:
 Error: Session could not be loaded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However Changing adapter to mongo in session.js worked.